# Send data to controller using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, web, laravel-blade

I am new to Ajax and I am using laravel, now i want to have a delete button that will send the id of the item that i want to delete to controller. Here is my code.

Views

```
<div class="row">
@foreach($photos as $photo)
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1">
    <button onclick="removeItem({{$photo->id}}); return false;">Delete</button>   
  </div> 
@endforeach
</div>
```

Here is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function removeItem($myvar) {
  $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "deletephoto",
  );}
}
</script>
```

I want to send this to this route

```
Route::post('deletephoto','GamefarmsController@deletephoto');
```

on my Controller I want to do this just to test if its working

```
public function deletephoto()
{
    dd($myvar);
}
```

Comment: You don't make an ajax request in `removeItem()`. Read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: oh sorry mispasted the code

Comment: And what is the question? What isn't working?

Comment: I just want to send data to my controller. I did this to test it dd($myvar);

Comment: Edit your question and add your real code for `removeItem()`

Comment: Here is an example that you can follow: http://blog.igeek.info/2013/using-ajax-in-laravel/

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your variable $myvar to the data-property of the $.ajax() function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "deletephoto",
    data: { myvar: $myvar }
})
```

Then in your controller you can get the value of this variable with:

```
Input::get('myvar'); // for Laravel 4.x
Request::input('myvar'); // for Laravel 5
```

Comment: Thanks you sir gonna try it

Comment: I tried it sir, but the die and dump is not showing on screen

Comment: Do you get a succesful response (200)? Maybe the url isn't right?

Comment: the url is right I got this route   Route::post('deletephoto','GamefarmsController@deletephoto');

Comment: @jakebalba you won't see the response on the screen, you can only see it in the javascript console - because AJAX doesn't refresh the page. You have to send a response to the page and then console.log() it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function removeItem(myvar) {
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "deletephoto",
    data: { 'myvar' : myvar },
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    }
)};
}
</script>
```

In your routes.php file:

```
Route::post('deletephoto', array(
    'as' => 'deletephoto',
    'uses' => 'GamefarmsController@deletephoto');
));
```

In your controller:

```
public function deletephoto() {
    //dd($myvar);
    return Input::get('myvar');
}
```

This will return whatever the variable passed through was, and send it back to the AJAX call, and then output in the console.

And finally:

```
<button onclick="removeItem({{$photo->id}});">Delete</button>
```

Comment: got this first error on the console SyntaxError: missing } after property list

Comment: and when i click the button i got this ReferenceError: removeItem is not defined

Comment: @jakebalba Please see updated answer, note the change in the JQuery/Javascript as well

Comment: @jakebalba Sorry, forgot to take the `$` out from the parameter

Comment: @jakebalba try `removeItem({{ $photo->id }});` Notice the **space** between the brackets and the variable.